# run .msi setup file after accessing web site from server to client

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a web application in ASP.NET, with C#. I am getting the following message in my browser window when accessing the application:

```
---------------------------
Windows Internet Explorer
---------------------------
Stop running this script?
A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly.
If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive.
```

I researched into the problem and found the following link, which is proposed as a solution to this problem:

[http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500#FixItForMeAlways)

I want to execute this setup when a client accesses the web site for the first time. How can I run this setup on the client side?

Comment: Get the browser to autorun an installer? Good luck with that.  There's security mechanisms in place to prevent exactly that sort of thing from happening...

Comment: Long running scripts are considered as bad design. You should make them faster instead of hacking IE settings.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to fully automatically run some program from a website as @cHao said, this is what all browsers prevent.
But you may look at ClickOnce deployment, it allows for very fast and easy installation of your program literally in one click.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).aspx